# O que é arquitetura de software?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software

O que significa o termo "arquitetura de software" e como o termo se diferencia de "engenharia de software"?

Comment: Uma pergunta interessante. Parece que são as mesmas coisas ou as diferenças não sejam significativas.

Answer (score 5):

**[Arquitetura de software](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitetura_de_software)**: estuda a organização global dos sistemas, relacionamentos e componentes. Ela permite o entendimento dos componentes de um sistemas.

**[Engenharia de Software](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engenharia_de_software)**: são os conceitos, métodos e os processos relacionados ao desenvolvimento. Essa parte inclui a especificação, desenvolvimento, projeto, verificação, validação e gerenciamento.

Podemos dizer que o engenheiro projeta e quem desenvolve a base é o arquiteto, definindo tecnologias e estruturas que serão utilizadas.